# When is a reaction feasible at room temperature?

Tags: energy, temperature

Gibbs free energy determines whether a reaction will occur spontaneously or not. Still, the activation barrier of a reaction determines if a reaction will occur at a given temperature. At any non-zero temperature every energy level will be populated *somehow*, but when is population high enough to say that a reaction will take place?

So when is a reaction called feasible at room temperature? A source on this with an energy range for the barrier that can be overcome at a specific temperature (kJ or kcal/mol) so that one considers the reaction actually taking place would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related: [How to relate a reaction barrier to the time the reaction needs to proceed?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/61602/7951)